# Converting kriging grid to polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, convert, kriging

I have an Excel file with coordinates and a measured value belonging to this coordinates. In ArcMap I can display the points and color it concerning the measured values. Since most of the values close to each other have the same value, I want to build polygons out of them.

I thought the easiest way to do so would be to interpolate via kriging. However, now I don't find a way to create a polygon out of the resulting kriging grid. By using `Conversion Tools --> from Raster --> Raster to Polygon` the Input Field for Raster tells me:

> The resulted Kriging Grid is not in the correct data format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to reclassify your raster data using the [Reclassify tool](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000sr000000.htm). Then, run the `Raster to Polygon` tool and it should run fine. What's happening with the "incorrect data format" error is that you have a continuous (smooth) raster, and it is trying to convert that to a polygon.